# How to call a method from an Active Choice Parameter script in Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I was trying to use your Active Choice plugin to dynamically change one of my build’s options, based on another chosen parameter.
I wrote a Groovy script that calls a method declared outside the parameter’s scope that should return a list of options based on the other parameter.

Please see this snippet of code (I changed it a bit to simplify):

```
def getBranchesOfEnv(env) {
     def output = sh(script: "git branch", returnStdout: true)
     def branches = output.readLines()
     println("Branches list: ${branches}")
     return branches
}
 
properties([
     parameters([
          choice (
               name: 'ENV',
               choices: ['PROD', 'DEV', 'TEST',],
               description: 'Select environment'
          ),
          [
               $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
               choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
               description: 'Select branch',
               name: 'BRANCH',
               referencedParameters: 'ENV',
               filterable: true,
               script: [
                    $class: 'GroovyScript',
                    fallbackScript: [
                         classpath: [],
                         sandbox: true,
                         script: "return ['Could not get Environment from ENV Param']"
                    ],
                    script: [
                         classpath: [],
                         sandbox: true,
                         script: '''
                         if (ENV.equals("PROD") || ENV.equals("DEV")) {
                              return getBranchesOfEnv(ENV)
                         } else {
                              return ["N/A"]
                         }
                         '''
                    ]
               ]
          ]
     ])
])
```

I also tried calling the method like this: return "${getBranchesOfEnv(ENV)}"
But with no success. I always get the fallback script result in the dropdown.

If I change the script to these quotes """ and call "${getBranchesOfEnvRepo(ENV)}" it retrieves the default "PROD" values only and changing the ENV parameter to "DEV" for example, won’t affect the BRNACH dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

The getBranchesOfEnv method is defined outside the parameters. It might not be accessible inside the parameter script. Jenkins’ DSL scope might not allow this kind of method invocation directly.

You can solve it with this example:

```
    def getBranchesOfEnv(env) {
        // your code here
    }
    if (ENV.equals("PROD") || ENV.equals("DEV")) {
        return getBranchesOfEnv(ENV)
    } else {
        return ["N/A"]
    }
```

Comment: that doesnt solve it..as it's not dynamic.  the solution i have found is everything has to be part of string interpolation...sadly